# How does XCode find classes without headers?

Tags: objective-c, header-files, declaration

I'm trying to get rid of unneeded headers in my XCode project by taking them out one at a time and seeing if they cause a compiler error.

Sometimes, I can take out a header that declares a class, and Xcode still lets me use it.

For example, I took out `#import "Chartboost.h"`, but there was no error on the line `Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];`

Option-clicking on `Chartboost` says it is declared in `NSObject.h`

How can my code still `compile` when I'm not importing the header file!?

Comment: Well objective-c relies on messaging, and you can send any message to any object, regardless of if it implements it or not.  At least AFAIK

Comment: @StefanH Yeah, but that has nothing to do with compiler errors.

Comment: Make sure you do not ignore warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing Chartboost.h, but through one of the other imported headers. This way you don't need to clutter up every class header with an endless number of header-files. Too bad XCode isn't better at telling us which headers are already available...

Comment: Well, the first part of your answer is correct but I entirely oppose the idea of importing headers within other headers. Yes, sometimes that is needed (e.g. protocol definitions) but most of the time the proper use of forward declaration prevents us from having to create circular header imports. And as another hint for the OP, check your project's pch-file, that one might also import things you want to get rid off.

Comment: Are there any tools out there for finding unneeded imports?

Comment: I see your point, and of course you might easily break everything if you refactor and remove a header. Still, there is something to be said about extensive import statements in headers actually making it harder to keep track of dependencies. It might be easy to "miss the forest for the trees" so to speak...

Comment: The general rule I follow: if a class/controller has a direct dependency  on another class (such as creating instances of it), import it, even if another class may already import it. It doesn't cost anything extra-- `#import` makes sure it will only be included **once**, and the code won't break if another imported class no longer needs it and removes its own import of the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not importing Chartboost.h then **Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];** will most definitely give an error.The only possible explanation is that you might be importing some other file which in turn might be importing Chartboost.